# Laravel 4.2 - stop composer from updating particular package

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following dependency in composer.json:

```
"maatwebsite/excel": "1.*",
```

and I altered one of the classes to introduce some desired features, such as setting headers. Problem is, updating with composer overrides my changes.
What is the right way to handle this ? Specifying some way that I don`t want this package to be updated, or maybe extract this package somewhere in my source code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the version the exact current version, instead of the wildcard version you have now (*)

1.3 seems to be the newest 1.* version: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/tree/1.3

Answer (score 0):

You can check in `composer.lock` file for the current version of the dependency.
then you can put that exact version in your `composer.json` file instead of `"1.*"` this should fix your problem and it will not update the dependency when you do `composer update`

it should look like something `"maatwebsite/excel": "1.1.13"` or whatever the  targetted version is.